# Ng-repeat -how to avoid copying input content of div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am duplicating a `<div>` by using `ng-repeat`. When a button is clicked, a new but duplicated `<div>` element appear. The problem is that the user can add tasks in the list, and when I duplicate the div, it also duplicates the content. Here is my html which is repeated:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"  ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index">
        <div class="task-container">
            <div class="content-task-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s10">
                        <input id="task-input-{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="task">
                        <label for="task-input-{{$index}}">Write task here</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-add">
                        <a class="btn-floating" id="btn-add-task"><i class="material-icons" ng-click="addTask(task)">add</i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=show-tasks ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="task-{{$index}}"/>
                        <label for="task-{{$index}}">{{task}}</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller that both handles the adding of tasks in the list, and the duplication of the div element:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.owner = $routeParams.owner;

$scope.task = "";

$scope.tasks = [];

$scope.addTask = function(task) {
    console.log(task);
    $scope.tasks.push(task);
    $scope.task = "";   
};

$scope.inputCounter = 0;
$scope.inputs = [{
    id: 'input'
}];

$scope.cloneContainer = function() {
    console.log("inside cloneContainer()")
    $scope.inputTemplate = {
        id: 'input-' + $scope.inputCounter,
        name: ''
    };
    $scope.inputCounter += 1;
    $scope.inputs.push($scope.inputTemplate);
};

});
```

I've tried to give all the id elements an unique id, but this doesn't cut it. I also need the 'tasks' array to be unique for each div element in `ng-repeat`. Is there any way to achieve this?

A simple plunkr to illustrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/LtWXUG6MKU5TGFTXpWUn?p=preview

Comment: Not clear what issue is or what expected results are. Please update this demo with more detail http://plnkr.co/edit/LtWXUG6MKU5TGFTXpWUn?p=preview

Comment: The question seems clear to me.

All of your elements are sharing the same `$scope`, so they get the same `$scope.tasks`, so they contain the same data. Don't use a shared controller for data that needs separate scope; put each list of tasks inside a directive with isolate scope, and ng-repeat over that directive.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Do you have a simple code to illustrate how to get started? I've tried googling some, but it's quite confusing to be honest... I'm new to angular and I've never used a directive before.

Comment: Your main issue is that `tasks` should be child arrays of `inputs`. Then you push new task into appropriate child array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're conceptualizing this is a bit off -- don't think in terms of duplicating DOM nodes.  Instead think in terms of modifying your data model, each part of which happens to be rendered as a different DOM node.

In this case, you put all your data into a single shared controller, with a single "task" array; when you tried to create a new task list it wound up referring to the same task array and therefore appeared to be a duplicate of the original list.  (In fact it was a separate list, but referencing the same data from `$scope.tasks`.)

Here the controller contains `$scope.lists[]`, each element of which is itself an array of tasks:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.lists = [];
  $scope.addList = function() {
    $scope.lists.push([]); // start each new task list with an empty array
  };
});

app.directive('taskList', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      mylist: '=taskList' 
    },
    templateUrl: 'tasklist.html',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.addTask = function() {
        scope.mylist.push(scope.newtask);
        scope.newtask = '';
      };
    }
  };
});
```

You can see this in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jP3LGacZMox9o55uHffm?p=preview

Alternatively, you can keep the task data out of the controller altogether, and store it only in the directive.  (I tend to favor this approach where possible, using controllers only for data or functionality that needs to be shared across multiple directives):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.lists = [];
  $scope.addList = function() {
    $scope.lists.push(""); // here we only care about the length of the array, its content is irrelevant 
  };
});

app.directive('taskList', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'tasklist.html',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.mylist = []; // mylist is not passed in from the controller, so init it here. Each instance of the directive will have its own mylist array
      scope.addTask = function() {
        scope.mylist.push(scope.newtask);
        scope.newtask = '';
      };
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/A9JcCoK15Tt7Vzrj35fh?p=preview

Comment: Wow, thank you! Works like a charm :) Now I just how to understand WHY it works. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Generally you want to put shared data and functionality in a controller, and specific data/functionality in isolated directives.  I fudged that in the first example, all the list data is actually stored in the controller as nested arrays -- it'd probably be better to completely separate them.  I added a separate example demonstrating that.